How can I replace characters after a specific match + offset?
I have a file containing values that must be obscured (substituted for XX), but they are not always at the same position within the whole line, and I don't know their content. What I do know though, is their position relative to a specific match.
For instance, I want the third and fourth number after "00 00" to be substituted by XX
Original:
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 10 11 12 13 14

Desired Output:
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 XX XX 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 XX XX 12 13 14

I have tried with awk but I have only managed to position myself relative to the beginning of the line. Is there a way to index $2 and $3 from a specific match, for instance?
Edit: there can only be one occurence of 00 00 in the line, it can't contain 00 00 00 no need to worry about leading or trailing match.
My (embarrassing) attempt so far was:
cat file | awk -F'00 00' '{print $2}' | awk '{gsub ($3,"XX",$0);gsub ($4,"XX",$0)}1'

Aside from the multiple awks, I also lose the beginning of the lines, as anything before the match is dropped by my first awk

can 00 00 occur more than once in a line? could a line contain 00 00 00 and if so then do we replace based on the leading 00 00 or the trailing 00 00? If any of these scenarios can occur then please update the question with additional example lines showing these scenarios

@markp-fuso I edited my post, I want the 3rd and 4th placement after 00 00, my bad.

Here's one awk approach:
$ awk '
{ 
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ 
    if($i=="00" && $(i+1)=="00"){
      $(i+4)=$(i+5)="XX"
    }
  }
}1' file 
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 XX XX 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 XX XX 12 13 14

The idea is to iterate over all fields (for(i=1; i<=NF; i++); NF is the number of fields), and look for cases where the current field ($i) and the next one ($(i+1)) are both set to the string 00. Then, we change the 3rd and 4th field to XX ($(i+4)=$(i+5)="XX"; using +4 and +5 since I am counting from the first 00, not the second). Finally, we print everything. The default action for awk when an expression evaluates to true is to print the line, so the simple 1, which is always true, is often used as a shorthand for print.
Note that this has the drawback of replacing your field separator with a space. In this example, that doesn't seem to be an issue, but if it is, just specify the input and output separators. So if your input had commas you want to keep, you would do:
$ cat file 
AA,BB,CC,00,00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07
AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,00,00,08,09,10,11,12,13,14

$ awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
{ 
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ 
    if($i=="00" && $(i+1)=="00"){
      $(i+4)=$(i+5)="XX"
    }
  }
}1' file 
AA,BB,CC,00,00,01,02,XX,XX,05,06,07
AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,00,00,08,09,XX,XX,12,13,14


You could also just treat this as a simple substitution and do something like:
$ sed -E 's/( 00 00 .. ..) .. ../\1 XX XX/' file 
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 XX XX 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 XX XX 12 13 14

Or
$ perl -pe 's/( 00 00 .. ..) .. ../$1 XX XX/' file 
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 XX XX 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 XX XX 12 13 14


If you made the loop on that first awk script start at the end and count down rather than starting at 1 and counting up then you could stop at the first non-numeric field rather than looping through those too, i.e. for ( i=NF; $i~/[0-9]/; i--). That's trading a numeric for a regexp comparison on each loop iteration though so may not actually save any time. You could add a break after the XXs are assigned so you don't continue looping afterwards (the OP said it can only happen once per line) - that would save time.

It's easier with sed or perl than with awk unless you have a awk that supports gawk's gensub() extension:
sed 's/\(00 00 .. .. \).. ../\1XX XX/' < file

perl -pe 's/00 00 .. .. \K.. ../XX XX/' < file

gawk '{print gensub(/(00 00 .. .. ).. ../, "\\1XX XX", 1)}' < file

With POSIX awk, you can do:
awk '
  match($0, /00 00 .. .. .. ../) {
    $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART+11) "XX XX" substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  {print}' < file


Using awk:
$ awk 'match($0, /(00 ){2,}[0-9]+ [0-9]+/){ 
     len=RSTART+RLENGTH;
     printf "%s",substr($0,1,len);
     $0=substr($0,len+1);
     sub(/[0-9]+ [0-9]+/, "XX XX");}1' 

Assuming only numbers are repeated after 00 00.

This command uses gawk's split function.
$ awk -v var="XX XX"  '
   n=split($0,a, /00 00 .. .. .. ../, seps){
   $0="";
   sub(/.. ..$/, var,seps[1]);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)  $0 = $0 seps[i-1] a[i]}1'

First the current record($0) is split. This built-in function creates two arrays viz. a and seps(the separator array). Then $0 is set to "".
Then sub() is used to substitute var with fields to be replaced in array seps.
The awk command splits fields by GNU awk's built-in function split.

n = split(s, array, sep)
splits the the string s into array[1], ..., array[n]. The
number of elements found is returned. If the sep argument is provided, it is used as the field separator; otherwise FS is used.
From  Awk — A Pattern Scanning and Processing Language

split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])
Divide string into pieces separated by fieldsep and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the seps array.
From Effective AWK Programming by Arnold Robbins.

I got your point. $0 = $0 seps[i-1] a[i] is better (clearer) than $0 = (!$0) ? a[i] : $0 seps[i-1] a[i]. I've edited the command. And thanks.

Using any awk:
$ awk 's=index($0,"00 00") {$0=substr($0,1,s+11) "XX XX" substr($0,s+17)} 1' file
AA BB CC 00 00 01 02 XX XX 05 06 07
AA BB CC DD EE FF 00 00 08 09 XX XX 12 13 14

